# Android Versions Size Vs Features

Tags: performance, android-versions, operating-system

This occurred to me while updating Windows laptop. Each version of Windows gets bigger, much bigger in size compared to the extra benefits to "average Joe (or Jane)".

**Question**: What is the size of pure Android version starting from 1.0 to current 6.0 (less the skin added by OEM) and key benefits or improvements (for the average user) added in each Android version ?

Comment: Since JB, you can see the changelog here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Answer (score 2):

For versions above 2.3.6, you could check the [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) page for the stock images for the nexus phones. They could provide a context for the sizes of pure Android.

There is another site i had seen comparing all the features of all the versions of Android. I can't seem to remember the name though

Edit: Found the site [here](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/android-versions-comparison).

Comment: Thank you . I should have specified in my question that problem is getting inputs on earlier versions